# Null pointer exception Chrome Driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Null pointer exception.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\chromedriver_win32_2.1"));

ChromeDriver d1 = new ChromeDriver();
```

Hi All,

I am trying to automate ChromeDriver. But it is throwing this error. Can someone please help me?

Comment: please post the full stack trace

Comment: _"C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\chromedriver_win32_2.1"_ didn't you forget the `.exe` part? Did you unpack the .zip archive?

Answer (score 2):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\chromedriver_win32_2.1"));
```

This is flat-out wrong. It should be

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\chromedriver_win32_2.1\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Notice that I dropped the `System.getProperty()` call which did nothing (returned `null`) and I added `\\chromedriver.exe` to your path since you need to provide a full path with the exucutable included (and the downloaded .zip file unpacked).

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of two things:

1. One of your setProperty arguments are null (either the key doesn't exist/typo, or the getProperty doesnt exist/typo
2. Your getProperty method is using only one argument, so the system is expecting this to be the key. I doubt your property key is going to be a full directory, so you'll need to use the double argument `getProperty(key, value).`

Source:
[Get/Set Property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperties%28java.util.Properties%29)